# Where does Android SDK Manager install Android Sources?

Tags: android

I have installed the "Sources for Android SDK" option according to the below image:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

but where are they installed?  Is there any obvious way to find out what folder contains them?

Comment: Check in your default android sdk folder, there will be one folder named source.

Comment: I see a folder named "sources" with a bunch of android-XX folders.  Is that it?

Comment: android-XX yes it is.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I had a feeling it would be that obvious.  If you re-post your comment as an answer I will choose it!